Failing to run benchmarks
I'm failing to execute benchmarks on my machine while others can on the same branch, while using the same command.
I'm getting the error:
Error: Input("No benchmarks found which match your input.")

Edit: the command I run for example:
./target/release/bfg-node benchmark pallet --chain=dev --wasm-execution=compiled --pallet=pallet_assets --steps=50 --repeat=20 --json --template ./scripts/frame-weight-template.hbs --output=./ -extrinsic=

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

I missed a '-' before the 'extrinsic' flag. So in stead of: ... --extrinsic=
I had: ... -extrinsic=
Will open an issue
